# R data.table upsert operation

Tags: r, data.table, upsert

I didn't find how to perform an upsert operation with data.table.

For the example, consider I have:

```
library(data.table)
> (a=data.table(x=1:2,y=1:2))
   x y
1: 1 1
2: 2 2
> (b=data.table(x=c(1,3),y=c(10,1)))
   x  y
1: 1 10
2: 3  1
```

I tried

```
> merge(a,b,all=TRUE)
   x  y
1: 1  1
2: 1 10
3: 2  2
4: 3  1
```

and

```
> a[b,on="x",mult="last"]
   x  y i.y
1: 1  1  10
2: 3 NA   1
```

Wanted result

```
   x y
1: 1 10
2: 2 2
3: 3 1
```

I did google without finding the answer.

To complete, the question is even more generalist as I do have several data.table with more than 300 columns. In my case, one of those columns contains a year that distinguish data; which leads to the proposed possibilities / answers.

In case one does not have such column available from start, one can easily add it to reflect merge/upsert priority prior applying the solution.

Comment: How about `rbind(a, b)[, .(y = max(y)), by = x]`?

Comment: Perhaps `rbind(a,b)[order(x,-y)][!duplicated(x)]`

Comment: This works for this example but I do have more than 300 columns, not sure I want to write all names. Plus: is this an efficient way with `rbind` (data.table way)

Comment: Checked: I do have another column (say y) containing a date, so that I can use @akrun tip based on this column. What if I didn't? Add a duplicate of the key?

Comment: @EricLecoutre  You can update your post with the column/columns you have so that we can test it

Comment: It happens that data I have to merge are in fact yearly -- I will post what I ended up as a solution - credits for you @akrun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
unique(rbind(a,b), by = "x", fromLast = TRUE)
```

This makes entries unique in terms of the x column, with priority given to the last entry having each x value.

It extends to more columns `by = c("x", "y")`. It also extends to cases where you have more than two tables. Either replace `rbind(a,b)` with `rbind(a,b,c,...)`; or, if the tables are in a list, `rbindlist(L)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @akrun and considered I do have additional column(s) allowing me to distinguish between data, here is a solution.

```
> (a=data.table(x=1:2,y=1:2,year=2013))
   x y year
1: 1 1 2013
2: 2 2 2013
> (b=data.table(x=c(1,3),y=c(10,1),year=2014))
   x  y year
1: 1 10 2014
2: 3  1 2014
> (c=data.table(x=c(1,3,4),y=c(100,99,4),year=2015))
   x   y year
1: 1 100 2015
2: 3  99 2015
3: 4   4 2015
> rbind(a,b,c)[order(x,-year)][!duplicated(x)]
   x   y year
1: 1 100 2015
2: 2   2 2013
3: 3  99 2015
4: 4   4 2015
```

Comment: Considering yours is the only answer, I think you can safely update the question to reflect this extension instead of only showing it down here. Personally, I might do `unique(rbind(a,b,c), by="x", fromLast = TRUE)`, similar to the `duplicated` thing.

Comment: Thanks Frank, didn't know this syntax. If I find time, I will benchmark on my real (big) data but this should be faster that applying the double order + have the great benefit to directly see priorities in upsert. Also it works in all cases without requiring this additional column such as year in my case. Please post your answer as it seems more adequate to answer in broad generic problem.